# PostBackTrigger control id

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, triggers

I have an button ("export") to export data from grid to excel.

But it's inside an update panel. So I'm registering postback trigger.

What should I assign to PostBackTrigger.ControlId ???

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the button is in the update panel you don't net to set a trigger for it.

If you've got any contorl outside the updatepanel you'll need to set a trigger if you'ld like the updatepanel to refresh. the ControlId should be set with the ID of the control.

[UpdatePanel Control Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx)