# Update panel can not find the button which trigger it

Tags: asp.net, triggers, updatepanel

I have a button is inside a another table(s) inside the update panel.

```
<Update panel>
<ContentTemplate>
<table>
  <table>
    <Button>
 <table>
<table>
</ContentTemplate>
</Update panel>
```

I would like to add a button to Update panel's trigger. 
But am getting an err says "Update panel can not find the button which trigger it".

I am getting "Sys.Webforms.PageRequestmanagerParseErrorException: This message recieved from manager could not be parsed. Common cause for this error are when response is modified by response.write"

Please help!

Comment: Duplicated - You've just asked the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989862/postbacktrigger-control-id/3990097#3990097

Comment: It's not same question. I have found this is the issue. And asked if ther s any workaround.

Comment: But a button in a UpdatePanel doesn't need to be set as a trigger. "By default, any postback control inside an UpdatePanel control causes an asynchronous postback and refreshes the panel's content."

Comment: My "button" is to export data...which will export grid data to excel...When I am exporting some data by clicking on export..I am getting a "popup"(system generated).

Answer (score 1):

PostBackTrigger example:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
  <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Button 1-Partial Postback" />
  <asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" Text="Button 2-Full Postback" />
 </ContentTemplate>
 <Triggers>
  <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btn2" />
 </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Here, in ur example... we have buttons inside update panel..then (as u said) why do go for trigger ? (Or did u just gave an exaample ???)

Comment: There are 2 types of Triggers: AsyncPostBackTrigger and PostBackTrigger. you don't need to set an AsyncPostBackTrigger for a control that is in the UpdatePanel.

Comment: here my buttons are not directly inside update panel..but they inside 2 nested tables which are inside the update panel. So my update panel is not able to locate the button, it says.